# How I Can use Linq Query count no. of record in query

Tags: linq

```
var emailToProcess = 
    from a in db.EmailNotToProcess
    join b in EmailUids on a.ENTPUId equals b.Uid
    where a.ENTPUId != b.Uid
    select b;
```

Here EmailUids is a List and EmailUid is a struct inside the struct we have two option like

```
public int EmailId;
public string Uid;
```

this ..

so I am executing the query but I am not able to count the how much record in this query...

thanks....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx) method:

```
var emailToProcess = from a in db.EmailNotToProcess
                     join b in EmailUids on a.ENTPUId equals b.Uid
                     where a.ENTPUId != b.Uid
                     select b;
int emailCount = emailToProcess.Count();
```

Comment: Hi Dear it's not working for u suggest it will give me error just like..Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

Comment: @Jitendra, I see, you probably need to use `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()`. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Dear Frédéric Hamidi Just I Could Test AsEnumerable() as well as ToList() but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Jitendra, do you still receive the same error? It might come from the query itself then. You might have to call `AsEnumerable()` on `EmailsNotToProcess`, depending on its type.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info on "it doesn't work"? Exception? Returns 0 while there are records?

Comment: emailToProcess.Count() 'emailToProcess.Count()' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' int {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: After further analysis, it looks like `EmailUids` is not fetched from the database. LINQ to SQL cannot join a table to a local array or list. You'll probably have to rewrite your query.

Comment: You can't join a db table with a local sequence (in memory Array, List, or whatever) with Linq2Sql.
Calling ToList() on the table will probably solve the exception, but is not a good idea if its a big table

Comment: Dear Frédéric Hamidi u have a teamview or Go To Meeting so u can see my exact problem..

Comment: @Jitendra, sorry, I don't think you can get that level of service from StackOverflow... not from me at least :)

Comment: Yes, rewrite your query so it doesn't join to `EmailUids`. Maybe you can use `Contains()` instead?

Comment: Sweet. Didn't realise that count() executes the query and returns the number of records. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to join an SQL Table via Linq-SQL with an external `List`, which I dont think is supported

Comment: No I am not join as SQL Table The list is like a simple List<EamilId> and EmailId is the struct.

Comment: db.EmailNotToProcess is an SQL table, EmailUids is an external (to SQL) list. I dont think joining them is supported

Answer (score 1):

If there are only a handful of ID's in the List then you can use Contains. This will pass each integer to SQL as a parameter:

```
var emailToProcess = from a in db.EmailNotToProcess
                     where !EmailUids.Select(u => u.Uid).Contains(a.ENTPUId)
                     select b; 

int count = emailToProcess.Count();
```

NOTE:

If there are 1000's of IDs in EmailUids then you'll have to rethink your strategy. Either move the list of ID's into a SQL table (so LinqToSQL can perform the translation from LINQ to raw SQL) or you will have to pull back the entire rowset for EmailNotToProcess and then perform the join on the client.

It's hard to advise without knowing how much data you're dealing with in each table/list.

Comment: That's probably better than what I wrote. Combined in the complete query, I think it might work :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a Contains:

```
var emailToProcess = 
    from mail in 
        (from a in db.EmailNotToProcess
         where EmailUids.Select(e => e.Uid).Contains(a.ENTPUI)
         select a).AsEnumerable()
    join b in EmailUids on mail.ENTPUId equals b.Uid
    where mail.ENTPUId != b.Uid
    select b;

int count = emailToProcess.Count();
```

Comment: I am getting error like this....                                    the best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HMBL.MailManager.EmailUid>.Contains(HMBL.MailManager.EmailUid)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Edited, can you try again? I'm sorry but I'm walking in the dark here :)

Comment: It's Working but I am not able to count any no.of Record I am getting only 0(Zero) result...actully my target resule is 11

Comment: Try decomposing the query in half and see the results in debug mode. Something like:(from a in db.EmailNotToProcess
         where EmailUids.Select(e => e.Uid).Contains(a.ENTPUI)
         select a).ToList()

Comment: And see if there are results from the database. If there are, then it must be the local join that fails. I think from now on you are close to a solution but you need to debug it to find where the issue is.