# Convert SQL query using 'count' clause, to LinQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

My SQL Server query (below) works perfectly fine, and I'm trying to convert it to LinQ in C#.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT addressline3, city, COUNT(*) as 'InstitutionNumber'
FROM institutionenquiries
WHERE CITY = 'AHMEDABAD'
GROUP BY addressline3, city
ORDER BY city;
```

Desired output is:

[image]

I'm able to draw the LinQ query in below format, which gives me correct output
(except for `COUNT(*) as 'InstitutionNumber'`).

**LINQ Query:**

```
var obj = (from u in dbContext.InstitutionEnquiry
           where u.City == data.Trim().ToLower()
           select new {
               AddressLine3 = u.AddressLine3.Trim().ToLower(),
               City = u.City.Trim().ToLower(),
               InstitutionNumber = (from a in dbContext.InstitutionEnquiry
                                    where a.City == data.Trim().ToLower()
                                    select a).Count()
           }).ToList();
```

This gives me count for **`'InstitutionNumber' = 3`** for all.

I'm not able to get the count aspect correctly. I've referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407259/how-i-can-use-linq-query-count-no-of-record-in-query) post's answer and it gives me only count, but I'm not able to nest it within my LinQ query.
Any helpful inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you converting 'data' to lowercase (u.City == data.Trim().ToLower()) when the 'u' from database is in uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this LinQ :

```
var obj = dbContext.InstitutionEnquiry
        // WHERE CITY = 'AHMEDABAD'
        .Where(w => w.City == "AHMEDABAD")  // => Note           
        // GROUP BY addressline3, city
        .GroupBy(g => new {g.AddressLine3, g.City})
        // SELECT addressline3, city, COUNT(*) as 'InstitutionNumber'
        .Select(c => new {c.Key.AddressLine3, c.Key.City, InstitutionNumber = c.Count()})
        // ORDER BY city
        .OrderBy(o=> o.City)
        .ToList();
```

Note: For ignoring case sensitivity You can use :

```
.Where(string.Equals(w.City.Trim(), data.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first observation is that since SQL has a GROUP BY, LINQ should have a GroupBy, too.

The second observation is that since non-aggregate columns in SQL are group by columns, the results you select in LINQ would come from the group's key.

Now we can write the query:

```
var res = dbContext.InstitutionEnquiry
.Where(u => u.City == data.Trim().ToLower())
.GroupBy(u => new {
    AddressLine3 = u.AddressLine3.Trim().ToLower(),
    City = u.City.Trim().ToLower()
 }).Select(g => new {
     g.Key.AddressLine3,
     g.Key.City,
     Count = g.Count()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ :

```
var obj = (from p in dbContext.InstitutionEnquiry
group p by new
{
    p.addressline3,
    p.city
} into grp
select new
{
    grp.Key.addressline3,
    grp.Key.city,
    InstitutionNumber = grp.Count(),
}).ToList();
```

Equivalent Lambda expression :

```
var obj = dbContext.InstitutionEnquiry
.GroupBy(p => new { p.addressline3, p.city})
.Select(p => new { p.Key.addressline3, p.Key.city, InstitutionNumber = p.Count() })
.ToList();
```